# select multiple dropdowns value (all) based on the first dropdown selected value

Tags: javascript, select, dropdown

How to change the selected value for all dropdowns (childselect1, ..2, ..3) value based on the first (motherselect) selected value by Javascript only?

```
    <select name="motherselect" id="motherselect">
     <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
        <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
        <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
    ..
    
    
    <select name="childselect1" id="childselect">
     <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
        <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
        <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
    ..
    <select name="childselect2" id="childselect">
     <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
        <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
        <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
    ..
    <select name="childselect3" id="childselect">
     <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
        <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
        <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
    ..
 <select name="childselect4" .. 
..until 100 and more
```

made it working so it changes, but only the first:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        //Attach onchange event to dropdownist
        $('#motherselect').on('change', function() {
          //Set the motherselect dropdownlist value based on childselect selected value
          $('#childselect').val($('#motherselect :selected').val());
        });
      });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data attribute on any parent e.g. `data-select-id` and associate children to it using `data-select-parent-id`.

Wire everything-up based on those attribute selectors. No need to mess with IDs or class names.

**Note:** You cannot have more than one element with the same ID. They must be unique. I replaced all the `id="childselect"` attributes with `class="childselect"`.

```js
const handleParentChange = (e) => {
  const
    $select = $(e.target),
    selectId = $select.data('select-id');
  if (!selectId) return;
  $(`[data-select-parent-id=${selectId}]`).val($select.val());
};

$('[data-select-id]').on('change', handleParentChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="motherselect" class="motherselect" data-select-id="1">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
  <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
  <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
</select>
<select name="childselect1" class="childselect" data-select-parent-id="1">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
  <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
  <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
</select>
<select name="childselect2" class="childselect" data-select-parent-id="1">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
  <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
  <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
</select>
<select name="childselect3" class="childselect" data-select-parent-id="1">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
  <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
  <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
</select>
```

If you want the JS to work with your existing HTML, you could try this:

```js
const handleParentChange = (e) => {
  $('.childselect').val($(e.target).val());
};

$('.motherselect').on('change', handleParentChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="motherselect" class="motherselect">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
  <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
  <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
</select>
<select name="childselect1" class="childselect">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
  <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
  <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
</select>
<select name="childselect2" class="childselect">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
  <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
  <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
</select>
<select name="childselect3" class="childselect">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
  <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
  <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
</select>
```

The problem with the code above is that there is no way to group the inputs given the presented HTML.

Here is a modified version where elements are logically, grouped:

```js
const handleParentChange = (e) => {
  const
    $select = $(e.target),
    $group = $select.closest('.groupselect');
  $group.find('.childselect').val($select.val());
};

$('.motherselect').on('change', handleParentChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="groupselect">
  <select name="motherselect" class="motherselect">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
    <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
    <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
  </select>
  <select name="childselect1" class="childselect">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
    <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
    <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
  </select>
  <select name="childselect2" class="childselect">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
    <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
    <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
  </select>
  <select name="childselect3" class="childselect">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">none</option>
    <option value="7401" required="">7401</option>
    <option value="7402" required="">7402</option>
  </select>
</div>
```